# Method to approximate continuous functions by smooth functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, approximation-theory

Sorry that this is informal, I don't know what formalizes this idea.

Let's say we have a function, which, like $|x|$ has many "sharp corners" or even perhaps cusps. Well, I don't like those sharp corners because they're not infinitely differentiable. Is there a method to approximate a zig-zag or cusp-filled function by a smooth function with rounded corners?

Comment: [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) gives you uniform approximation by polynomials on a compact of $\mathbb{R}$. Look for [constructive proof](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404996001600). For example, using [Bernstein polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial#Approximating_continuous_functions)

Comment: There are several ways to approximate a function by another. Do you care about them being close at every point? Then @user85667's comment is an excellent suggestion. Do you care about the difference being small in the sense that if $f$ is the function that you want to approximate and $g$ is the smooth approximation then the difference integrates little over your domain? Then you might want to learn about convolutions (or anyhow, as they are very powerful tools for this). If you specify in which sense you want the approximation to be optimal, we can refine our answers.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of $f(x) = |x|$ on $\mathbb R,$ we could let $f_n(x)=\sqrt {1/n^2+x^2}, n=1,2, \dots$ Then each $f_n$ is smooth and $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le 1/n$ for all $n$ and all $x.$

Answer (score 2):

There is a general approach of approximating $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$ by functions $f_h = f * \rho_{h}$, sometimes called [mollification](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20mollifiers%20(also%20known,generalized)%20functions%2C%20via%20convolution.) of $f$. Notably, we have $f_h \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and $f_h \to f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, if $f$ is differentiable, then $(f_h)' = (f')_{h}$, so we get convergence of derivatives too. There are also convergence results for rougher $f$, e.g. $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$.